# How to get variable array from controller and then view with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

I've success get data on controller with php native and show in the view
the code like this:

controller

```
function help(){
    $data['result'] = array("name" => "jason", "age" => 20);
    $this->load->view('profiles', $data); }
```

and view like this

```
foreach ($result as $key) {
    echo $key;
}
```

and result will be show
"jason 20"

The question is how to execute like that with ajax without load the url?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: yes i'm using jquery @ProfNandaa

Answer (score 1):

in the controller return a JSON object

```
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode( $result ));`enter code here
```

then in the view call the controller with jquery

```
 `$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/controller')?>",
                    data: {some_val: val},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                         console.log(value.name);
                         console.log(value.age);



                    }
                });
```